# What is the point of std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak when it just uses _InterlockedCompareExchange intrinsic?

Tags: c++, std, atomic

Looking trough the implementation of compare_exchange_weak in `<atomic>` on Visual Studio 2017, on every type of memory ordering, it calls the same function:

```
inline int _Compare_exchange_release_4(volatile _Uint4_t *_Tgt,
    _Uint4_t *_Exp, _Uint4_t _Value)
    {   /* compare and exchange values atomically with
            release memory order */
    _Uint4_t _Old_exp = *_Exp;  /* read before atomic operation */

    _Uint4_t _Prev = _INTRIN_RELEASE(_InterlockedCompareExchange)((volatile long *)_Tgt,
        _Value, _Old_exp);

    if (_Prev == _Old_exp)
        return (1);
    else
        {   /* copy old value */
        *_Exp = _Prev;
        return (0);
        }
    }
```

(the code is an example from the Release ordering, but all the versions of the function are the same)

So it just uses the intrinsic `_InterlockedCompareExchange`, and i don't see anything in MSDN about this function failing, so what's the point of these checks? Why not call `_InterlockedCompareExchange` directly?

Comment: It is portable between compilers and operating systems that may all use different intrinsics.

Comment: @Galik That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: In general, Intel x86/x86_64 have fairly strong ordering in any case, so most of the memory ordering arguments will act the same on most compilers.  But IIRC, architectures like ARM/AArch64 and MIPS have looser memory ordering constraints that allow for the different memory ordering arguments to be implemented with less overhead.